# MSTest & Silverlight Unit Test Framework Tutorials

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mstest

I'm sorry if this appears elsewhere, it may be that my Google-Fu is failing me.

I'm in the process of reading Roy Osherove's [The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274) and am thrilled to be able to start doing some Test-First work on my current project.

Roy's book uses NUnit as the basis for it's training.  I find myself in the position of needing to use MSTEst in VS 2008 Pro along with the Silverlight Unit Test Framework to do our testing.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorials and references entries for using both of these tools?

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the test class attributes for MSTest are identical to that of NUnit.  You should be able to use Osherove's book as a guide without too much impedance mismatch.